# jQuery moving a div across the screen, bit by bit

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

So I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).keypress(function(e)
            {
                switch(e.which)
                {
                    // user presses the "a"
                    case 97:    $('#character').css('left','+=40');
                }
            }
}
```

The problem is that I can only press "a" once and #character moves only once...

I also have jQuery draggable enabled (http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) with a constrained area around it.

How come I can only move the div once with keypress?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that jQuery will interpret that "+=40" on a call to `.css()`. I suspect that it only moves once because the first time you blast away whatever the "left" value originally was and set it to the string "+=40", which the browser ignores. Subsequent clicks just repeat that.

I might be wrong, but I've been reading the jQuery source and I see nothing to suggest that the `.css()` function does what `.animate()` does with values like that.

You might try using `.animate()` directly:

```
case 97:    $('#character').animate({'left': '+=40'}, 1);
```

Comment: Agree. And you might as well use `animate()` with duration set to 0. Would have the same effect as if `css()` supported `+=`

Comment: Thanks @peirix I don't use `.animate()` much so I wasn't 100% sure that 0 would work.  I suspect you're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function to the second parameter of `.css()` where you can manually do some manipulation on the value to set.

Try this:

```
       // The 'left' parameter in the function references the current position.

case 97:$('#character').css('left',function(i,left){
                                    return parseInt(left) + 40;
                                });
```

**EDIT:** As noted by **@Gaby**, the call to `.replace('px','')` was unnecessary, as `.parseInt()` takes care of that automatically.

Comment: although it is more concise, removing the `px` is not necessary as `parseInt` will only deal with the first number it finds in the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to get the position of the character, add 40 to it's left and then apply the css change, for example

```
var pos = $("#character").offset();

$("#character").animate({"left": pos.left + 40}, 100);
```

If you're storing the position of the character somewhere else you can also just update that value and update it's position in the game loop.

Comment: jQuery will understand the "+=" notation in a call to `.animate()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it does anything at all!

your missing a couple ); 
and i also  tweaked it a bit. this works!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            // user presses the "a"   
            case 97:
                var left = parseInt($('#character').css('left')) + 40;

                $('#character').css('left', left + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```